# Google Maps InfoWindow opens on load, not onclick

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infowindow

I've been working on this forever, and I am so close! First time using CustomMarker and MarkerCluster.

The following javascript works perfectly, except the infowindows are all open, when the page loads. I want them to open on click of the marker.

```
<script>
function initMap() {
    var newYork = {lat: 40.7127837, lng: -74.00594130000002};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("user-matches-map"), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(newYork),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var markers = []
    var matches = $.getJSON('get_json_matches', function(matches){
        var matches = matches
        for(i=0; i < matches.length; i++) {
            //console.log(matches[i])
            var firstName = matches[i][1]
            var lat = matches[i][4]
            var lng = matches[i][5]
            var slugUrl = matches[i][6]

            //get the user's image, and if it's missing, call the correct image path
            if(matches[i][0] === "thumb/missing.png") {
                var image = "http://localhost:3000/assets/medium/missing-e38aa1831b278c511eff9812efc6fda028d46b3b94f71cc88c3e0ba0e99ff19e.png"
            } else {
                var image = "http://" + location.host + matches[i][0];
            }

            //if the user has lat lng, plot them on the map
            if (lat != null) {
                var contentString = '<div>'+'<h1>Hello '+ firstName +'</h1>'+'</div>'
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: contentString
                });

                marker = new CustomMarker(
                    new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng), 
                    map, 
                    image, 
                    firstName, 
                    contentString)
                marker.info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: contentString
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
                )(marker, i));
                markers.push(marker);
            } 
        }
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
        {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
});

}
initMap();

function CustomMarker(latlng, map, imageSrc, firstName, contentString) {
    this.latlng_ = latlng;
    this.imageSrc = imageSrc;
    this.firstName = firstName
    $(this).on('click', function (event) {
        console.log('click')
    });
    // Once the LatLng and text are set, add the overlay to the map.  This will
    // trigger a call to panes_changed which should in turn call draw.
    this.setMap(map);
}
CustomMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
CustomMarker.prototype.draw = function () {
    // Check if the div has been created.
    var div = this.div_;
    if (!div) {
        // Create a overlay text DIV
        div = this.div_ = document.createElement('div');
        // Create the DIV representing our CustomMarker
        div.className = "customMarker"
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = this.imageSrc;
        div.appendChild(img);
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(marker, "click", function (event) {
            google.maps.event.trigger(me, "click");
        });
        // Then add the overlay to the DOM
        var panes = this.getPanes();
        panes.overlayImage.appendChild(div);
    }
    // Position the overlay 
    var point = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.latlng_);
    if (point) {
        div.style.left = point.x + 'px';
        div.style.top = point.y + 'px';
    }
};
CustomMarker.prototype.remove = function () {
    // Check if the overlay was on the map and needs to be removed.
    if (this.div_) {
        this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
        this.div_ = null;
    }
};
//create a prototype of the image marker
CustomMarker.prototype.getPosition = function () {
    return this.latlng_;
};
</script>
```

Why are the infowindows open on load, if they are in an eventListener function?

Please let me know if you need more details. Thanks!

Comment: Because that's an [IIFE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) that you're using

Comment: this `(function (marker, i) {
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
                )(marker, i)` is an IIFE - in effect you are passing the result of calling this function as the third argument to `google.maps.event.addListener` - whereas, you need to pass a function

Comment: Thank you, I've never heard of IFEE. When I delete the 3rd argument, calling the function: `(marker, i)` it does not initiate on click. I also just tried to change it to `marker.addListener('click', function() { infowindow.open(map, marker);});` but that doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you've created an [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)

From [wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression):

> An immediately-invoked function expression (or IIFE, pronounced
>   "iffy") is a JavaScript programming language idiom which produces a
>   lexical scope using JavaScript's function scoping. Immediately-invoked
>   function expressions can be used to avoid variable hoisting from
>   within blocks, protect against polluting the global environment and
>   simultaneously allow public access to methods while retaining privacy
>   for variables defined within the function.

The part where the click handler for the marker is added, your script does the following:

Create an anonymous function, passing it the current `marker` (and index `i`) and immediately execute it:

```
(function (marker, i) { infowindow.open(map, marker); })(marker, i)
```

The result of this IIFE (`undefined`) is than used as the click handler for the marker:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', undefined);
```

Unless you can switch to ES6 and [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) you will have to use an IIFE to prevent scoping issues:

[Javascript infamous Loop issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue)
[JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

---

To make your script work, you have to change this part:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
})(marker, i));
```

To:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker) {  // I've removed the index because it is unused
    return function() { infowindow.open(map, marker); };
})(marker));
```

Comment: I've actually tried that as well, but in this case, no click event happens. When I click on one of the markers, I can see in the console that the click event is not triggered.